# Hide a program from being visible on the desktop

Tags: windows-7

is there anyway of making a running program completely invisible on Windows [7], so it does not show up on the desktop at all. Basically i want to make every instance of firefox that is opened run 'invisibly', so while it is open [and working], it is not visible to the user at all.

(I have code which opens up Firefox (using Selenium) to test webpages - however constantly having windows opening up is annoying as i use the machine for general work - hence my desire to designate every instance of the program that loads as invisible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a virtual machine to run these tests. 
You could easily use virtual box with any free Linux OS.
This way you can have it running at all times without being an issue on your working machine.

Comment: Thanks - ended up going for virtual desktop instead (as simpler to set up & can still access my files)